# knockout custom binding not firing update

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Yep another one of this question. Unfortunately none of the other answers like these have helped: 
[Knockout custom binding not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654340/knockout-custom-binding-not-updating)

[Possible to fire custom binding update except initially?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985620/possible-to-fire-custom-binding-update-except-initially)

[Knockout custom binding for bootstrap select not updating viewmodel "selectedCategories/selectedCategory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35929754/knockout-custom-binding-for-bootstrap-select-not-updating-viewmodel-selectedcat)

[Update is not called in knockout.js custom binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915461/update-is-not-called-in-knockout-js-custom-binding)

[Custom Binding not working updating from Knockout 2.3 to 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635396/custom-binding-not-working-updating-from-knockout-2-3-to-3-3)

[Knockout, noUiSlider, custom bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33490510/knockout-nouislider-custom-bindings)

[Knockout custom binding update function not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465083/knockout-custom-binding-update-function-not-firing)

Tried all these and update is still not firing!!!

As the html binding isn't accepted as a virtual biding I'm trying to create my own because template in my case will not work!

The html inside a foreach:

```
...
<!-- ko ifnot: $parent.raceData.sufficientFPS -->
    <!-- ko fktml: resultItem.html --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
...
```

The javascript:

```
...
this.html = ko.observable('<td>1</td><td>Lastname</td><td>something 1</td><td>something 2</td><td>something 3</td><td>something 4</td>').extend({ notify: 'always' }); 
// doesn't work with or without notify always

ko.bindingHandlers.fktml = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        console.log(value);
        addUpdatedHtml(element, value);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        console.log('update', element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext, value);
        addUpdatedHtml(element, value);
    }
};
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.fktml = true;
...
```

For each item in my foreach init and update is called once. But nothing ever happens when I update `this.html()` and yes, I have checked that it is updated. And what most other answers say is to use ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()) which doesn't only gives me the value the first time and then does nothing.

How can I get punch in this knockout binding?

Comment: Tried to reproduce in a fiddle but everything seems to work... What did I do differently? Are you sure the problem isn't inside your `addUpdatedHtml` method? https://jsfiddle.net/dyr7737x/

Comment: (Remove the `.extend` in the fiddle to see there's no difference https://jsfiddle.net/xLhrzx1z/)

Comment: Tried without `.extend`, no difference. Also works fine in init and the first update. To be sure I commented that part but I still never get the console message after the first time. :(